# xslt split mp3 tag into artist and title

Tags: xslt, text, split

Many times, mp3 tags are in the form of "artist - title", but stored in the title field.

I want to split values into artist + title fields.

Examples of before/after split:

```
<title>Artist - Title</title>
<title> - Title</title>
<title>Artist - </title>
<title>A title</title>
```

After:

```
<artist>Artist</artist><<title>Title</title>
<artist /><title>Title</title>
<artist>Artist</artist><title />
<artist /><title>A title</title>
```

I haven't done much in programming in XSLT, so I don't know if the idiom I'd use in regular languages would fit, and if it does, what XSLT language elements would best be used.

This is how I would approach it normally:

1. calculate the position of the first " - "
2. if it is not found, return the `title` element as is and an empty `artist` element
3. if it is found at position 0, then remove it from the `title` element, then return the rest of the `title` tag as new `title` element and an empty `artist` element
4. if it is found at position length-3, then remove it from the `title` element, then return the rest of the `title` tag as new `artist` element and an empty `title` element
5. it it is found at a position larger than 0, copy everything till the position as `artist` element, return everything after it as new `title` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for the talk about 'removing' and so on, which don't apply (XSLT programs read input and produce output; they do not change their input), your description is a pretty good match.  Here (not tested) is how one might write it (except that I wouldn't comment it quite this heavily):

```
<xsl:template match="title">
  <!--* input often has artist - title in title element *-->
  <!--* So emit an artist element and populate it with
      * the string value preceding the hyphen.
      * (If there is no hyphen, string-before(.,'-') returns ''.)
      * Normalize space to lose the pre-hyphen blank.
      * If hyphens can appear in normal titles, change '-'
      * to ' - '.
      *-->
  <xsl:element name="artist">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(
                          substring-before(.,'-'))"/>
  </xsl:element>

  <!--* Now emit a title with the rest of the value. *-->
  <xsl:element name="title">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains(.,'-')">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(
                              substring-after(.,'-'))"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: +1; Thanks a lot. Especially about the "XSLT programs read input and produce output; they do not change their input". I had been thinking about the big idiom difference between XSLT and the languages I regularly use, but couldn't get my mind turn in the right direction to phrase it. Your description is exactly what I needed to start making that turn.

Comment: Accepted. I changed it towards the `<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,' - ')"/>` parts as - though hardly documented - `' - '` usually is the mp3/m3u tag delimiter (you don't want to split on the `A` from `A-ha`, the `T` from `T-Spoon` or `T-Pain` as they are valid artists).