# detect availability of node-set() function in xslt implementation of icecast server

Tags: xslt, node-set

Icecast contains an XSLT implementation based on [libxslt](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/) from [xmlsoft](http://xmlsoft.org).

I want to know if it supports the [node-set()](http://www.exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/) function, preferably in a way that works for other web-only environments too:

> Regrettably, the XSLT processor in icecast is only web accessible through the web
>   interface of the icecast process (so no [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html) on the commandline).
>   To worsen it: there is limited logging of the XSLT errors (when you do
>   things wrong, the icecast process often just dies).

I'm running icecast 2.3.2 as that is the [latest Windows based build](http://downloads.xiph.org/releases/icecast/) (there is [no 2.3.3 build for Windows yet](http://www.icecast.org/download.php)), which has libxslt.dll dated in 2008. There is no version number in the DLL, the best I can provide is this (see XSLT code at the bottom):

```
Version:    1.0
Vendor:     libxslt
Vendor URL: http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/
```

I tried running the node-set detection mentioned at [David Carlisle's blog](http://dpcarlisle.blogspot.nl) article [The EXSLT node-set function](http://dpcarlisle.blogspot.nl/2007/05/exslt-node-set-function.html) pointed to by "[How to use node-set function in a platform-independent way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92076/how-to-use-node-set-function-in-a-platform-independent-way)".

From the output, I think that fails:

```
icemaster@localhost972990localhost00EarthIcecast 2.3.2Sun, 23 Jun 2013 20:02:19 W. Europe Daylight Time202200ice-samplerate=44100;ice-bitrate=64;ice-channels=264StationGenre6424410000http://localhost:8000.....
```

What would be the best way to find out through an XSL file in the web-interface?

Version script:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
Version:    <xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')" />
Vendor:     <xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor')" />
Vendor URL: <xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor-url')" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

node-set script I tried:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  exclude-result-prefixes="exslt msxsl">

<xsl:output
  omit-xml-declaration="no"
  method="html"
  indent="yes"
  encoding="UTF-8" />

<msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="exslt">
 this['node-set'] =  function (x) {
  return x;
  }
</msxsl:script>

<xsl:variable name="x">
  <y/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="x">
  <html>
    <head><title>test exslt node set</title></head>
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="exslt:node-set($x)/*"/>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="y">
  <p>node set!</p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If it was XSLT 3 you'd have this option: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#func-function-available

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer**

> [libxslt](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/html) in icecast supports the [xt:node-set()](http://www.jclark.com/xml/xt-old.html#node-set) function.
>   Underneath it is implemented in by the [xsltFunctionNodeSet()](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/html/libxslt-extra.html#xsltFunctionNodeSet)
>   function.

**Generic answer**

I created a solution, based on the [CSTUG bibliography XSLT](http://bulletin.cstug.cz/xml/documents/bibliography.xsl.html) using the [function system-property](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_systemproperty.asp).

Please comment if this is indeed the correct way to do this.

The CSTUG code handles these node-set() functions:

- exslt:node-set()
- msxml:node-set()
- xalanc:nodeset()

I added support for these as well:

- xt:node-set()
- saxon6:node-set()

Output from icecast:

```
Version:    1.0
Vendor:     libxslt
Vendor URL: http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/
node-set(): xt:node-set()
```

XSLT used:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common"
  xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:xalanc="http://xml.apache.org/xalanc"
  xmlns:xt="http://www.jclark.com/xt"
  xmlns:saxon6="http://icl.com/saxon"
  extension-element-prefixes="exslt msxml xalanc xt saxon6"
  exclude-result-prefixes="exslt msxml xalanc xt saxon6"
  >

  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>
Version:    </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')" />
    <xsl:text>
Vendor:     </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor')" />
    <xsl:text>
Vendor URL: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor-url')" />
<!--
Prefixes used for node-set()
exslt: EXSLT aware processors (Saxon, xsltproc, Xalan-J, jd.xslt, 4XSLT)
msxml: MSXML
xalanc: Xalan-C, Xalan-J 2.6.x
xt: XT, libxslt
saxon6: Saxon 6
-->
    <xsl:text>
node-set(): </xsl:text>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="function-available('exslt:node-set')">
        <xsl:text>exslt:node-set()</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="function-available('msxml:node-set')">
        <xsl:text>msxml:node-set()</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="function-available('xalanc:nodeset')">
        <xsl:text>xalanc:nodeset()</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="function-available('xt:node-set')">
        <xsl:text>xt:node-set()</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="function-available('saxon6:node-set')">
        <xsl:text>saxon6:node-set()</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>EXSLT:node-set not found!</xsl:text>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```